# How can I paste Markdown in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: markdown, microsoft-teams

I am trying to paste markdown in Microsoft Teams to speed up my workflow, but the pasted markdown remains as text. When I type the markdown myself, it works (as you can see on the screenshot). Sending the message as is doesn't help either.

I know that [Microsoft Teams support markdown](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772). Is there a workaround this?

[image: Markdown unformatted in Microsoft Teams]

Comment: If teams isn't supporting pasted markdown on purpose, then it would be ideal if you could paste in a bunch of markdown, then hit a button to rerender everything that you pasted as rich text from markdown, instead of it not working at all, or it working kind of if you delete one side of it the markdown and then type it back in. (though that solution isn't viable for many lines of markdown)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is a known issue, and as far as I know, Microsoft doesn't seem to be working on it.

One way to work this around (as you allowed *workarounds*) is to paste your markdown code to any editor/converter that produces rich text, copy the rich text, and paste it to Microsoft Teams.

Any online markdown editor will work. I tested with [Dillenger](https://dillinger.io/) and [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io) but I'm quite sure there are many other online editors you can paste your markdown code, copy the preview, and paste into Teams.

If you are using VSCode, you can use [the native markdown preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown) to generate a rich text, copy from it, and paste into Teams. Both Teams and Code are MS products so I guess they would work well together (just guessing with no hard argument). At least the pasted result seems good enough to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is what I have been doing so far.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add anything to help your situation. AFAIK Teams just doesn't have the feature.

Comment: I am using Teams like few hours. It appears it is not **built on markdown** , if that is the case I have to look elsewhere. Even that would mean more time spent on coaching non-technical people in org.

Comment: Perhaps a better solution than what I used… ie. for example for bold, removing the ending start and typing it back… Then the part is bold. But if, for example, you have `*Foo:*` and your deletion / typing is too fast, it changes the `:*` to an emoji… Very consistent…

Comment: For bigger chunks of markdown that might work but still - typing (multiple?) single line code block(s) with backticks really drives me crazy as the cursor moves to (what feels like) random places during typing while the starting backtick gets removed and the ending one not. I cannot imagine that the MS Teams devs really use it themselfs because in my humble opinion they would have fixed it for the sake of their own sanity.

Comment: Shameless plug for Obsidian, where you can write markdown then hit a button and render it. After that you can copy and paste into teams. Lots of other cool features for a really easy to use note taking app.

Comment: This seems to work on Mac - paste some formatted table (e.g., output from `knitr::kable()`) from RStudio into TextEdit, then paste that into a code block (```) in Teams.

Comment: When copying from VSCode, the text retains the color that it is given in VSCode. If your VSCode is in dark mode and your Teams is in light mode (or your recepient's Teams is in light mode), then the text will appear white on white except for links and code.

Answer (score 7):

If you have pandoc and powershell; the following converts your markdown to interpreted HTML;

```
Get-Clipboard | pandoc | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml
```

I find this a useful workaround because my markdown is usually coming from where I take my notes; vim. So in vim I can bind;

```
" In visual mode, Shift-v to copy selection to clipboard
vn V "+y
" In normal mode, Ctrl-m to convert clipboard Markdown to interpreted HTML
nn <c-m> :! powershell -Command "Get-Clipboard \| pandoc \| Set-Clipboard -AsHtml"<cr>
```

And I'm shift-v, ctrl-m away from having pretty notes on my clipboard to paste into Teams.

I think it's not also a stretch to imagine a Teams Extension that would do this in Teams.

Edit: I was getting some encoding issues. The command in my vimrc has evolved as follows.

```
nn <c-m> :silent ! powershell -Command "[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Default; Get-Clipboard \| pandoc \| Set-Clipboard -AsHtml;"<cr>
```

Comment: I used this to fix encoding issues for one-off jobs, slightly easier for me to remember if my markdown is ascii anyways: `Get-Clipboard | pandoc --ascii | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml`

Answer (score 2):

I've stumbled on the same issue, and found a cute way, especially if you're already using VS Code as your preferred editor.

Start up VS Code, open up a new markdown file - use `Ctrl+K, M` to switch the language to Markdown, type your fancy message, click on the *Open Preview to the Side* option, copy the preview and paste in Teams. It works pretty well.

Tested on Windows only, though.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Inline block of code**

Type `` `<space> ``int my_code = 0;`` `<space> ``

```
int my_code = 0;
```

**2) Multi-line code block**

Type backtick `` ` `` three times followed space

````
```<optional language><type space here>
int my_code = 0
````

Example for python

````py
```python<space>
int my_code = 0
````

Optional language can be **c** or **python** for example.
Adding extra space after backticks is essential.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-microsoft-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772

Comment: Please try for less noisy markdown formatting. I do not think that standing out this way attract the kind of attention to your post that you desire.